# Uniformization theorem for $C^k$ surfaces?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, compact-manifolds

Does the uniformization theorem apply for surfaces that are $C^k$ ($k<\infty$)? I'm familiar with a couple of proofs of Uniformization (using Riemann-Roch, Ricci flow). But most of these proofs assume that the surface is smooth i.e. $C^\infty$ or even analytic. I was wondering if the theorem still works if the surface is only $C^k$ for some $1\leq k<\infty$. I have tried looking for a reference but was unsuccessful.

In particular, I would like to show that a compact, orientable $C^1$ genus-$0$ surface is conformal to $S^2$.

One possible route would be to use one of the several approximation/density theorems for $C^\infty$ manifolds in the space of $C^k$ manifolds.

Comment: A $C^k $ manifold is always $C^k$ diffeomorphic to a $C^\infty$ manifold.

Comment: Yes, but does that help prove that a 2d, genus-0 compact $C^k$ Riemannian manifold is conformally diffeomorphic to $S^2$?

Comment: @ArcticChar: I think what one would need is something like the statement that a $C^k$ manifold equipped with a $C^k$ Riemannian metric is always $C^k$ isometric to some $C^\infty$ manifold equipped with a $C^\infty$ Riemannian metric. But I don't know Riemannian geometry well enough to know whether such a theorem exists.

Comment: Yes, I agree @LeeMosher. I posted the comment when reading only the first paragraph.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure such a statement is false in general. I vaguely recall that $C^1$ Riemannian manifolds can be pretty weird beasts. But I don't know about $C^2$ or higher.

Comment: These notes have some relevant information:http://people.math.sc.edu/howard/Notes/conformal.pdf

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking: Are you asking for a conformal map of the same regularity as the metrics on surfaces? As surfaces themselves? Note that each $C^1$-smooth surface admits a compatible $C^\infty$ atlas. The uniformization theorem even works for $L^\infty$-metrics (subject to the condition that the $L^\infty$-norm of the  Beltrami differential of the metric is $<1$). In particular, it holds for continuous metrics on compact $C^\infty$-surfaces. However, the conformal map will not be $C^\infty$, of course.

Comment: Ideally a conformal map with the same regularity as the surface. Could you give me a reference for the uniformization theorem for $L^\infty$ metrics?

Comment: It will be in any textbook on quasiconformal maps (say, Ahlfors, or Lehto). Some people call it "Measurable Riemann Mapping Theorem."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is Gauss' theorem on isothermal coordinates in the low-regularity setting.  It is known to analysts as Morrey's theorem and proofs can be found in many places, for instance:

*Ahlfors, Lars V.*, Lectures on quasiconformal mappings, Princeton, N.J.-Toronto-New York-London: D. Van Nostrand Company. Inc. 146 p. (1966). [ZBL0138.06002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0138.06002).

*Lehto, Olli*, Univalent functions and Teichmüller spaces, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 109. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. XII, 257 p. DM 124.00 (1987). [ZBL0606.30001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0606.30001).

Suppose that $ds^2= Edx^2 + F dxdy + Gdy^2$ is a measurable Riemannian metric on a bounded domain $U$ in the xy-plane, which is regarded as the complex plane. The Beltrami differential of this metric is defined as
$$
\mu= \frac{E - G + 2iF}{E + G + 2\sqrt{EG - F^2}}. 
$$
Suppose, in addition, that $||\mu||_\infty<1$ in $U$, which is true, for instance, if $ds^2$ is the restriction  of a continuous Riemannian metric on a larger domain $\Omega$ such that $cl(U)$ is a compact in $\Omega$. Then the measurable Riemann mapping theorem, first proven independently by Lavrentiev and Morrey in 1930s states that there exists an essentially unique (unique, up to postcomposition with a conformal automorphism of the unit disk) quasiconformal homeomorphism $f=f_\mu: U\to \Delta$ ($\Delta$ is the unit disk), which is a conformal isomorphism between $(U, ds^2)$ and the Euclidean metric on $\Delta$. I will not define conformality here, suffices to say that it preserves angles between tangent vectors a.e. in $U$ and preserves orientation.

Quasiconformal maps belong to the Sobolev class $W^{1,2}_{loc}$. If you want higher regularity, you can use for instance

*Lehto, Olli*, On the differentiability of quasi-conformal mappings with prescribed complex dilatation, Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn., Ser. A I 275, 28 p. (1960). [ZBL0090.05301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0090.05301).

which implies that if $\mu$ is locally Lipschitz-continuous, then $f_\mu$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism, hence, is conformal in the traditional sense of Riemannian geometry.

For surfaces this can be used as follows. Start with, say, a $C^1$-smooth surface $S$. (You can as well assume $C^\infty$, since there is always a compatible $C^\infty$ atlas.) Let $ds^2$ be, say, a Lipchitz-continuous Riemannian metric on $S$. (A $C^1$-smooth metric will, of course, suffice.) What's important here is the regularity of the metric, not the regularity of a surface.

Now, using  Lehto's theorem, find a compatible atlas consisting of $C^1$-smooth quasiconformal maps to domains in ${\mathbb C}$ which map conformally $ds^2$ to the Euclidean metric. The transition maps will be conformal and, hence, you get a Riemann surface structure on $S$. By the Uniformization theorem for Riemann surfaces, you get a conformal isomorphism from the universal cover of $S$ to, say, the unit disk. With respect to the original smooth structure on $S$, this map will be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism.  In particular, $(S,ds^2)$ will be conformally-isomorphic to a hyperbolic metric on $S$, where the conformal isomorphism is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism.  The same proof works for other conformal types: Euclidean and spherical.